# What is this image file's format?

Tags: image, format

I have a sample image file that's in something called RAW format.  I have never heard of this format and I don't know what it is.  The file begins with the following byte sequence:

```
E1 A9 02 00 84 0A 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E1 A9 02
```

Can anyone tell me what kind of image file this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it yourself. It's [RAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why that article didn't come up for me when I searched for it.

Answer (score 0):

A `RAW` image format is what is captured by camera's light-sensing chip.  `RAW` is its own image format; there are several applications out there that you can use to work with `RAW` images.  Here are a few: [Scarab Darkroom](http://dottech.org/93873/windows-how-to-convert-raw-images/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20dottechdotorg%20%28dotTech.org%20General%20Feed%29), [FileFilter](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/filefilter-is-the-ultimate-tool-to-organize-raw-data-from-text-files/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Addictivetips%20%28AddictiveTips%29), and my favourite, [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.php).  XnView is a regular image viewer, and `RAW` is one of the file formats it can read.